# I want to make all attributes of an object to disappear using an onclick event under certain condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object with the ID of "CR224" and within that object the word and number MGH66 exist.

I have a button named "Close" and want to perform an onclick task on the button that will cause the ID "CR224" to disappear [ probably using the style=
"none" attribute ] by using MGH66 as a trigger. This mean that when MGH66 not exist within the ID "CR224" then when I click "Close" will not make all the attributes of  "CR224" to disappear.

if possible I want it applicable :

1. With javascript.
2. Without javascript, the code directly embeded in the html body because some sites not accepting the script tag.

This is what I'm working on right now :

```
    <div id="LPA" style="background-color:red); width:200px; height:200px;">
    <p>MGH66</p>
</div>
<p><a href="#" onclick="myFunction";>Close</a></p>
```

I'm looking something like [ I know I'm missing somecode ] :
     function myFunction () { CR224.indextOf(MGH66) > 0.style="none";

Comment: @Jason T
That is too simple, the condition are not met where MGH66 within ID CR224 have to exist in order for the onclick event to work

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to target the thing you want to make disappear via document.getElementById()

I would suggest to use this function for your onclick:

```
function myFunc(){
    document.getElementById("LPA").style.display = "none";
}
```